# Is offline dictation officially supported by Apple?

Tags: ios, ios10, siri

I cannot seem to find any official documentation on this. This is what I have found so far using not-so-reliable means:

- Voice to text used to require an internet connection prior to iOS 9
- [In iOS 9, Apple experimented with offline dictation for certain
  devices](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/426k5e/til_ios_9_enabled_offline_dictation_on_iphone_6s/)
- [In a later revision of iOS 9, Apple removed offline dictation.](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/4syw10/ysk_offline_dictation_was_never_officially/)
- Apple re-introduced Offline Dictation in iOS 10. I have checked this on about a dozen iOS 10 devices. The ones with A9 processor show this option and the ones without don't.

But I would like to get some official documentation on this before telling our clients that iOS now supports offline voice to text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208343

> On iPhone 6s or later, iPhone SE, and iPad Pro, you can dictate
>   without being connected to the Internet. Earlier models of iPhone and
>   iPad require an Internet connection.

So you are correct that devices with A9+ processor can use dictation offline